# Length of line overlap

Tags: gis, postgis

I have two lines, I use "ST_LineCrossingDirection" to detect if the two lines cross each other.
If they do cross, how do I check the length of the overlap? Is there a function that returns a metric to indicate the size of their overlap?
For example, lines that do intersect but are perpendicular, length of overlap would be minimum. For lines that intersect, and run on the same route for some distance, the length of the overlap could quanity "overlap distance"
Any tips to get this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`ST_Intersection` will give you a collection of pieces of the lines that are mutual, if you want a bit more tolerance use `ST_Buffer` on one of the lines first. Then do a `Sum()` of the `ST_Length` of those pieces.

Comment: Also, [ST_CollectionExtract(geom, 2)](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_CollectionExtract.html) may help to pick the LineStrings out of GeometryCollections for ST_Length.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use ST_length(ST_LineFromMultiPoint(ST_Intersection(geom1, geom2)))  since intersection was giving me a multipoint geometry object.
Thanks for you help!